# Reading a char array using %s i.e string specifier

Tags: c, arrays, char, dynamic-memory-allocation, format-specifiers

```
char *ptr=(char*)calloc(n,sizeof(int));
```

using the above, we can allocate memory for char array. But is reading it character-by-character mandatory`? How to read and access it using`%s` i.e the string format specifier?

Comment: Looks You are intended to create char array but second argument is `sizeof(int)` it should be `sizeof(char)`.

Answer (score 2):

Reading character by character is not mandatory and using exactly `%s` is susceptible to buffer overruns. Specifying the maximum number of characters to read, one less than the number of bytes in the buffer being populated, prevents the buffer overrun. For example `"%10s"` reads a maximum of ten characters then assigns the null terminating character so the target buffer requires at least 11 bytes.

However, as the code suggests that `n` is unknown at compile time using `%s` with a *dynamic* width is not possible explicitly. But it would be possible to construct the format specifier (the format specifier is not required to be a string literal):

```
char fmt[32];
sprintf(fmt, "%%%ds", n - 1); /* If 'n == 10' then 'fmt == %9s' */
if (1 == scanf(fmt, ptr))
{
    printf("[%s]\n", ptr);
}
```

An alternative would be [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets):

```
if (fgets(ptr, n, stdin))
{
}
```

but the behaviour is slightly different:

- `fgets()` does use whitespace to terminate input.
- `fgets()` will store the newline character if it encounters it.

Casting the return value of `calloc()` (or `malloc()` or `realloc()`) is unrequired (see  [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)) and the posted is confusing as it is allocating space for `int[n]` but is intended to be character array. Instead:

```
char* ptr = calloc(n, 1); /* 1 == sizeof(char) */
```

Also, if a null terminated string is being read into `ptr` the initialisation provided by `calloc()` is superfluous so a `malloc()` only would suffice:

```
char* ptr = malloc(n, 1);
```

And remember to `free()` whatever you `malloc()`d, `calloc()`d or `realloc()`d.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read such array using `%s` but make sure you have allocated enough memory for what you try to read(don't forget the terminating zero character!).